# How to do a recursive search for a word in the Boggle game board?

Tags: java, recursion, boggle

Can someone help me with a psuedocode or even the recursive formula that describes the recursive search for a word in the Boggle board so I can get started?

Comment: Regular Boggle or Super Boggle?

Comment: regular boggle game haha I didnt even know there was a super boggle

Comment: I have posted an implementation in Java here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/52824972/4523235

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a word list available somewhere, likely stored in a Trie data structure (I've created a working Trie with comments on improving its efficiency [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/41630/trie-tree-form-in-java)).

Once you have a Trie structure (a prefix tree) which allows you to search for words based on their prefixes, you would want to use a recursive method something like the following psudo-code.

```
char[][] gameBoard = new char[4][4];
List<String> wordList = new ArrayList<String>();
//fill in the game board with characters
//Start the word search at each letter
for(int x = 0; x < 4; x++){
    for(int y = 0; y < 4; y++){
        recursiveWordSearch(x, y, "");
    }
}
recursiveWordSearch(int x, int y, String word){
    //Concatenate gameBoard[x][y] to word.
    //Check to see if word is a valid word (check against your word list).
    //If word, add to wordList

    /*Check word list to see if any words contain current prefix. If not,
     then there's no point in continuing further (return). IE if AQZ isn't the 
     start of any word at all in the list, no reason to keep adding letters, it's
     never going to make a word.  */

    //Otherwise recursively call this method moving left/right/up/down
    recursiveWordSearch(x+1, y, word); //move right
    recursiveWordSearch(x, y+1, word); //move up
    recursiveWordSearch(x-1, y, word); //move left
    recursiveWordSearch(x, y-1, word); //move down
    /*You'll want to make sure that x-1, x+1, y-1 and y+1 are valid values before
     sending them. */


}
```

Answer (score 0):

To store valid words, data structure with methods that check is given string prefix of some valid word and is given string a valid word is needed, e.g. [Trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) data structure.

To find all possible valid words, we have to start word for each position, and than recursively visit each not visited neighbour. Here are two methods of python class that implements search of all valid words on given table:

```
def solve_with( self, ind, inds_passed, word):
    word += self.table[ind[0]][ind[1]]  # Add next character
    if self.trie.is_prefix(word):       # Is current string prefix of valid word
        if len(word) > 2 and self.trie.is_word(word):  # Is current string whole word
            self.ret.add(word)
        inds_passed.add(ind)            # Set this position as visited
        for n in self.neigbours(ind):   # Pass through all neighbours
            if n not in inds_passed:    # If not visited already
                self.solve_with(n, inds_passed, word)  # Recursive call
        inds_passed.discard(ind)        # Remove position as visited

def solve(self):
    self.ret = set()                    # Set of all word found on table
    for x in xrange(0, self.dim):       # Start search with each position
        for y in xrange(0, self.dim):
            self.solve_with( (x,y), set(), '')
    return self.ret
```

Answer (score 0):

Java implementation using DFS approach

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class WordBoggle {

static int[] dirx = { -1, 0, 0, 1 };
static int[] diry = { 0, -1, 1, 0 };

public static void main(String[] args) {
    char[][] board = { { 'A', 'B', 'C', 'E' }, { 'S', 'F', 'C', 'S' }, { 'A', 'D', 'E', 'E' } };

    String word = "ABFSADEESCCEA";
    System.out.println(exist(board, word));
}

static boolean exist(char[][] board, String word) {
    if (board == null || board.length == 0 || word == null || word.isEmpty())
        return false;
    boolean[][] visited = new boolean[board.length][board[0].length];
    for (int i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
        resetVisited(visited);
        for (int j = 0; j < board[0].length; j++) {
            if (board[i][j] == word.charAt(i)) {
                return DFS(board, word, i, j, 1, visited);
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}

static void resetVisited(boolean[][] visited) {
    for (int l = 0; l < visited.length; l++) {
        Arrays.fill(visited[l], false);
    }
}

static boolean DFS(char[][] board, String word, int i, int j, int k, boolean[][] visited) {
    visited[i][j] = true;
    if (k >= word.length())
        return true;
    for (int z = 0; z < 4; z++) {
        if (isValid(board, i + dirx[z], j + diry[z], visited)) {
            if (word.charAt(k) == board[i + dirx[z]][j + diry[z]]) {

                return DFS(board, word, i + dirx[z], j + diry[z], k + 1, visited);
            }

        }
    }
    return false;
}
```