# Searching multiple directions of a 2d array at once

Tags: java

I'm making a boggle application and am currently having issues with the searching method that checks if a word exists on the grid. If I have duplicates of the same letter next to each other and one of them doesn't lead to the word but the other does, the method returns false.

[image: Ex grid]

For example, good will return false because the O to it's bottom left will be checked first instead of the top right one which would lead to a correct answer.

```
    public boolean letterIndex(String target, char[][] board) {
    if(target.length() < 1) {
        System.out.println("Invalid, please enter a word");
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {//For loop iteratively traverses the array
        for (int j = 0; j < board[0].length; j++) {
            if (board[i][j] == target.charAt(0)) {//Checks for where on the board the first letter of the target word appears
                char[] temp = new char[target.length()];//Creates a temporary array that stores the target string as a character array
                temp[0] = target.charAt(0);//Sets the first index of the array as the first letter of the word
                return wordCheck(target, i, j, board, 1, temp);//Call wordcheck method
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
//Checks all the directions of the position passed by letterIndex recursively until either the word has been found or all directions return false
public static boolean wordCheck(String target, int row, int col, char[][] board, int index, char[] temp) {
    if (target.equals(String.valueOf(temp))) {//Checks every recursive run if the word has been found
        return true;
    }
    if (!target.equals(String.valueOf(temp))) {
        if (row + 1 < board.length) {//Check down
            if (board[row + 1][col] == target.charAt(index)) {
                temp[index] = board[row + 1][col];//Add the letter to the temp array
                index++;
                return wordCheck(target, row + 1, col, board, index, temp);
            }
        }
        if (col + 1 < board[0].length) {//Check right
            if (board[row][col + 1] == target.charAt(index)) {
                temp[index] = board[row][col + 1];//Add the letter to the temp array
                index++;
                return wordCheck(target, row, col + 1, board, index, temp);
            }
        }
        if (row - 1 >= 0) {//Check up
            if (board[row - 1][col] == target.charAt(index)) {
                temp[index] = board[row - 1][col];//Add the letter to the temp array
                index++;
                return wordCheck(target, row - 1, col, board, index, temp);
            }
        }
        if (col - 1 >= 0) {//Check left
            if (board[row][col - 1] == target.charAt(index)) {
                temp[index] = board[row][col - 1];//Add the letter to the temp array
                index++;
                return wordCheck(target, row, col - 1, board, index, temp);
            }
        }
        if (row - 1 >= 0 && col + 1 < board[0].length) {//Check upperright
            if (board[row - 1][col + 1] == target.charAt(index)) {
                temp[index] = board[row - 1][col + 1];//Add the letter to the temp array
                index++;
                return wordCheck(target, row - 1, col + 1, board, index, temp);
            }
        }
        if (row + 1 < board.length && col - 1 >= 0) {//Check lowerleft
            if (board[row + 1][col - 1] == target.charAt(index)) {
                temp[index] = board[row + 1][col - 1];//Add the letter to the temp array
                index++;
                return wordCheck(target, row + 1, col - 1, board, index, temp);
            }
        }
        if (row - 1 >= 0 && col - 1 >= 0) {//Check upperleft
            if (board[row - 1][col - 1] == target.charAt(index)) {
                temp[index] = board[row - 1][col - 1];//Add the letter to the temp array
                index++;
                return wordCheck(target, row - 1, col - 1, board, index, temp);
            }
        }
        if (row + 1 < board.length && col + 1 < board[0].length) {
            if (board[row + 1][col + 1] == target.charAt(index)) {//Check lowerright
                temp[index] = board[row + 1][col + 1];//Add the letter to the temp array
                index++;
                return wordCheck(target, row + 1, col + 1, board, index, temp);
            }
        }
    }
    return false; //If the next letter isn't in any direction, the word doesn't exist
}
```

I'm aware the issue is with the order of the if statements, is there a way to get the program to check all sides no matter what? Also, currently it only checks the first index of the letter (at letterArray) is there a way to get it to run wordCheck for all indexes of the letter?

Comment: That is because `letterIndex()` only calls `wordCheck()` once. It should make the call and return true if `wordCheck()` returns true, but continue if `wordCheck()` returns false. I.e. replace `return wordCheck(...);` with `if (wordCheck(...)) return true;`. The same goes for all the recursive calls in `wordCheck()` itself.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the return statement in `letterIndex`.  The way your code is written, `letterIndex` will always return after calling `wordCheck`, but it seems you want it to only return when `wordCheck` says it has found a word, otherwise you want to continue looking.  Does that help?

Comment: One other idea I’ll add that I’ve sometimes found helpful when doing 2d grid traversals like this is to try to avoid code duplication by making it easier to iterate all the neighbors of a cell.  That is, try to write your 8 checks as a single check in a loop.  It’s not trivial to do, but it may lead you to something interesting.

Comment: Would this improve efficiency, runtime, visibility, or some other factor I didn't mention? Or is this just good coding standard?

Comment: It can reduce code duplication and increase simplicity, which in turn makes it easier to reduce bugs or add functionality in the future.

Comment: In general, it’s good to try to find ways to avoid repeating yourself (the DRY principle).  In this case, it might or might not make your code nicer, but if you’re learning to code, the excercise will be a good learning experience either way.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is, to split your searchings into several different methods.

In your `wordCheck` method just check if any of the next directions leads to the target.

Example:

```java
public static boolean wordCheck(String target, int row, int col, char[][] board, int index, char[] temp) {
  return wordCheckDown(target, row, col, board, index, temp)
      || wordCheckRight(target, row, col, board, index, temp)
      || wordCheckUp(target, row, col, board, index, temp)
      || wordCheckLeft(target, row, col, board, index, temp)
      || wordCheckUpperRight(target, row, col, board, index, temp)
      || wordCheckLowerLeft(target, row, col, board, index, temp)
      || wordCheckUpperLeft(target, row, col, board, index, temp)
      || wordCheckLowerRight(target, row, col, board, index, temp);
}
```

In this method it will check for the word in all directions. The expression is "short circuit". That means, if in my example the `wordCheckDown` method returns true, the other methods are not evaluated. If `wordCheckDown` returns false, `wordCheckRight` is evaluated and so on.

In the direction-methods you then check if the next `char` fits and call the `wordCheck` method recursively, like in the example below for the `wordCheckLowerRight` method:

```java
private static boolean wordCheckLowerRight(String target, int row, int col, char[][] board, int index, char[] temp) {
  //Checks every recursive run if the word has been found
  if (target.equals(String.valueOf(temp))) {
    return true;
  }

  if (row + 1 < board.length && col + 1 < board[0].length) {
    if (board[row + 1][col + 1] == target.charAt(index)) { //Check lowerright
      temp[index] = board[row + 1][col + 1]; //Add the letter to the temp array
      index++;
      return wordCheck(target, row + 1, col + 1, board, index, temp);
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

In addition there is also a problem with your `letterIndex` method. You stop after checking the first `char` that is matching the starting letter of the word. Keep searching the whole field, while the word was not found.

E.g. you can use a `boolean` variable for this like in the example below:

```java
public static boolean letterIndex(String target, char[][] board) {
  if (target.length() < 1) {
    System.out.println("Invalid, please enter a word");
    return false;
  }

  boolean foundWord = false;

  for (int i = 0; i < board.length && !foundWord; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < board[0].length && !foundWord; j++) {
      if (board[i][j] == target.charAt(0)) {
        char[] temp = new char[target.length()];
        temp[0] = target.charAt(0);
        foundWord = wordCheck(target, i, j, board, 1, temp);
      }
    }
  }
  return foundWord;
}
```

In this example, the `for` loops check if the indexes of the array are met, and also if the word was already found.

Comment: That worked thank you! I'm a little concerned with how many methods are being called with this solution and am curious if there is a more efficient one. Any thoughts?

Comment: As described, when a target is found in any of the directions (e.g. `wordCheckDown`) the following ones are not executed because of the "short-circuit" operator `||`. Another example to clarify this: In your example image if you would search for "RFMA", then only `wordCheckDown` methods would be executed.

Comment: I see, so from what I understand is there is no issue with efficiency using this method correct? I do still have a concern about code visibility, it may seem a bit overwhelming.

Comment: I was mostly adapting the code of your example. I think you want to reduce code duplication: Maybe you want to take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23075689/how-to-do-a-recursive-search-for-a-word-in-the-boggle-game-board

A solution there is more compact i think